# How do I query for a set of all unique values present in my table?

Tags: python, django

I have this table:

```
class OwnerTransition(models.Model):
    owner_email = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=False)
    list_name = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=False)
    bounced = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
    onid_id = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('owner_email', 'list_name', 'bounced', 'onid_id',)
```

There can be multiple entries with the same *owner_email* as an owner can own multiple lists.  How would I write a query that returned a list of all the unique owner names present in *OwnerTransition*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`distinct`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) with `values`:

```
unique_emails = OwnerTransition.objects.order_by('owner_email').values('owner_email').distinct()
```

The docs discuss why the `order_by` call is necessary, and a shorter option you can use if you're using Postgres for your database.